# How to load data page by page in MS Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-reports

How do I load data page by page from the database into the MS Report viewer?

now I'm using following code:

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
            merchent = new Merchant();

            reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1";

            reportDataSource1.Value = merchent.GetProducts();
            this._reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
            this._reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../../Report1.rdlc";
            _reportViewer.RefreshReport();


}
```

here I want to add all data to DataSource at the initially. I want to add next page record set when clicking the next button.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Within ReportingServices you must set the InteractiveHeight to a number greater than 0. If it is set to 0 paging will be disabled

Comment: @Sreejith the way I read the question is to load & set the datasource once (as per code shown) and have one product per page. I didn't interpret this question to disable paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSRS [Page Breaks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207058.aspx).

Otherwise use the fact that SSRS honors white space to your advantage and deliberately put white space in your RDLC file to cause pagination.

[image]